# Можно ли увеличить стандартные значки автобусных остановок и метро

Tags: yandex-maps-api

можно ли увеличить стандартные значки автобусных остановок и метро?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас в отличии от веб-версии [Яндекс.Карт](https://yandex.ru/maps) в [JS API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/) все POI-метки отрисованы прямо на подложке. Они являются частью растровых тайлов и никакие изменения их внешнего вида не предусмотрены.